# How to use same JavaScript function in multiples Dropdownlists

Tags: javascript

I have multiple dropdown list added dynamically, and they get their own id, I have a function where I call OnChange event to pass some value based on selected in Dropdown list, but at the moment i am just doing this with the first select.

JS:

```
$("#id_detallepedido_set-0-producto").change(function () {
    producto_id = $(this).val();
    var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;

    $.ajax({              
    type: "GET",    
    url: url,                   
    data: {
        'producto': producto_id 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        console.log('Funciono!');
        console.log(data);
        $("#id_detallepedido_set-0-precio").val(data);       
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error' + data);
        //console.log(data);
    } 

    });        
});
```

"id_detallepedido_set-0-producto" is the id for the first Dropdownlist, and "id_detallepedido_set-0-precio" is the id for the field I pass the value based on selected value, there is anyway to use this function in every dropdown list added dynamically?

And I'm adding those dropdown list with Django Form here:

Html:

```
<table class="table" id="tPedidos">
  {{ detalle.management_form }}
  {% for form in detalle.forms %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
      <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        </thead>
    {% endif %}
      <tr class="formset_row-{{ formset.prefix }}">
        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
          <td>
            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
            {{ field }}
          </td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling dropdown change event using id, you can handle it using class. so it will execute for all dropdown.
But as you said your dropdown is added dynamically, **you need to create click event globally.**

let say you have 3 dropdown, then just add class = "mydropdownclass". and add class = "mytextfield" to your text control.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="t1" class="mydropdownclass">
                <option value="1">101</option>
                <option value="2">102</option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="test" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" class="mytextfield" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="t2" class="mydropdownclass">
                <option value="1">101</option>
                <option value="2">102</option>
            </select>

        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="test" />
        </td>

        <td>
            <input type="text" class="mytextfield" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
$(document).on("change", ".mydropdownclass" , function() {
    producto_id = $(this).val();
    var controlId = $(this).attr('id');

    //Updat textbox value
    $(this).closest("tr").find('.mytextfield').val($(this).val());

    var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;

    $.ajax({              
    type: "GET",    
    url: url,                   
    data: {
        'producto': producto_id 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        console.log('Funciono!');
        console.log(data);
        $("#"+controlId).val(data);       
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error' + data);
        //console.log(data);
    } 

    });        

});

</script>
```

you can check updated code [link]

https://jsfiddle.net/hubs3m0n/

Comment: this should be changed too
$("#id_detallepedido_set-0-precio").val(data);

Comment: I added <div class="mydropdownclass"></div> and inside I put it my table where I get the Dropdown lists added dynamically, but doing this now I cannot get "producto_id", in a console log its return in blank space

Comment: you need to add class in dropdown control, not in the div

Comment: Ok I got it to work, but know the id im passing in "controld" is the id for the dropdown field, not the price field Id where I put the value in success function

Comment: ohh, so all dropdown have its own div ?

Comment: post one div section with dropdown, so i can update code based on it.

Comment: No, im using the dropdown to selected a product, then I get the price based on that product and then I put that value in another field in the same row, you can see this picture to understand better: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISGhm.jpg

Comment: This is one of those field that is added dynamically too "<input type="number" name="detallepedido_set-0-precio" value="1" step="1" class="form-control" min="1" readonly id="id_detallepedido_set-0-precio">"

Comment: understood, but can you post html for single row ?

Comment: No im just doing it one post for all the table regardless of how many rows it have

Comment: ok, without checking hierarchyof your code, i can not help you, but i can guid you that give one more class to all div same  but not same as your dropdwon.
now when change event occur, you need to find nearest div of dropdown using class

Comment: So let me understand, i need to add a new class to all my "Prices Field" only or to all Fields in the row including Dropdown field?

Comment: no, let's say you have div where you want to show updated price, add class to that particular fiield. so when your change event occur using dropdown find nearest class control that you assigned to div and update it's value. still if you have any query you can post your html from browser console.

Comment: And what if I dont have a div between those field?, maybe im not understanding, this is one example of a row that is adding dynamically my form: https://imgur.com/a/4QyPWzF sorry if im not understanding what i need to do :/

Comment: Wow man now i got it! Thank you so much! Just added the find thing to a variable and then pass it to the succcess to put the price in the field like this: " $(p).val(data)" so this can help someone else in the future! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If elements are added dynamically you can attach an event to `document` like this.

```
$(document).on('change', '[write common selector here]', function callback() {})
```

Answer (score 0):

make a static class which will be same for every element and do in that way

```
$(".commonClass").change(function () {
    producto_id = $(this).val();
    var url = '/control/price/'+producto_id;

    $.ajax({              
    type: "GET",    
    url: url,                   
    data: {
        'producto': producto_id 
    },
    success: function (data) {   
        console.log('Funciono!');
        console.log(data);
        $("#id_detallepedido_set-0-precio").val(data);       
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert('error' + data);
        //console.log(data);
    } 

    });        
});
```